# How to add tabs to TabLayout using a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

How to add tabs to [TabLayout](https://github.com/hellodigers/TabLayout) using a `for` loop? I can't figure out the data-type of its [addTabs](https://github.com/hellodigers/TabLayout/blob/master/TabLayout/Classes/TabLayout.swift) parameter.

```
func addTabs(tabs: [(title: String?, image: UIImage?, controller: UIViewController)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an array of tuples.

`(title: String?, image: UIImage?, controller: UIViewController)` defines a [tuple](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID329).

`[ whatever ]` defines an array.

You can call it such as:

```
let myTuples = [ (title: "some title", image: someImage, controller: someController),  (title: "some title", image: someImage, controller: someController) ]
whatever.addTabs(tabs: myTuples)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an array of tuple

```
(title: String?, image: UIImage?, controller: UIViewController)
```